# Adding Selected Jtable row to a list model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I want this code to add one transaction to my list model when I select a row but it instead adds two transactions. Here is the code:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            String name = (String) table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
            Double price = Double.valueOf((String) table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1));
            String transaction = name + "         " + price;
            myModel.addElement(transaction);
            list.setModel(myModel);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Dont know the reason you are using `ListSelectionListener` here in your code. You can simply use button with `actionListener` and inside `actionPerformed` method do above task.

Answer (score 1):

A `ListSelectionListener` has an "is adjusting" property" that you need to check to make sure the selection has finished.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more information and working examples on how to test for this.

Or you can search the forum for other examples using a ListSelectionListener.